# Contar filas obtenidas en de una consulta con INNER JOIN en Mysql

Tags: mysql

tengo una consulta bastante larga, si funciona, pero no se como usar COUNT para obtener cuantas filas son en total mas no la información en sí, consulta en cuestión:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  tbl_docente.doc_cedula,
  tbl_docente.doc_nombre,
  tbl_docente.doc_apellido,
  tbl_docente.id_sede,
  tbl_docente.id_facultad,
  tbl_docente.id_carrera,
  tbl_publicacion.id_publicacion,
  tbl_publicacion.id_tipo_publicacion,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_titulo,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_nombre,
  tbl_publicacion.fuentebd,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_otros,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_sjr,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_codigo_lib_rev,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_seriado,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_seriado_dos,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_doi,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_url_public,
  tbl_publicacion.id_estado_public,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_rev_pares,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_filiacion,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_scaneo,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_scaneoa,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_fecha_envio,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_fecha_acepta,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_fecha_publicado,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_validado,
  tbl_publicacion.pub_estado
FROM
  tbl_docente
INNER JOIN
  tbl_publicacion ON tbl_docente.id_docente = tbl_publicacion.id_docente
WHERE
  tbl_publicacion.pub_estado = 1 AND tbl_publicacion.pub_validado = 'SI'
GROUP BY
  tbl_publicacion.pub_titulo
```

Comment: Sería algo como: **`SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM
  tbl_docente
INNER JOIN
  tbl_publicacion ON tbl_docente.id_docente = tbl_publicacion.id_docente
WHERE
  tbl_publicacion.pub_estado = 1 AND tbl_publicacion.pub_validado = 'SI'
GROUP BY
  tbl_publicacion.pub_titulo`**

Comment: gracias por tu comentario @A.Cedano pero no funciona, ya lo intente, incluso reduje la consulta pero aun no puedo.

Comment: Ojo,  si usas UNION en vez de UNION ALL, ya se está haciendo un SELECT DISTINCT implícito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta que la misma solución se puede reducir, mejor así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  count(tbl_docente.id_sede) as totales
FROM
  tbl_docente 
INNER JOIN
  tbl_publicacion ON tbl_docente.id_docente = tbl_publicacion.id_docente
WHERE
  tbl_docente.id_sede = 1 AND tbl_publicacion.id_estado_public = 3 AND tbl_publicacion.pub_validado = 'SI' AND pub_sjr LIKE '' OR NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
  count(tbl_docente.id_sede) as totales
FROM
  tbl_docente
INNER JOIN
  tbl_publicacion ON tbl_docente.id_docente = tbl_publicacion.id_docente
WHERE
  tbl_docente.id_sede = 1 AND tbl_publicacion.id_estado_public = 3 AND tbl_publicacion.pub_validado = 'SI' AND pub_sjr != '' OR NULL
```

En este caso solo saldrá esto (en mi caso mejor porque estoy generando unos gráficos estadísticos con Highcharts):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn, no es necesario agregar varias respuestas, debes agregar solo una realizada de acuerdo a [answer] , saludos.

Comment: te recomiendo borrar tus otras dos respuestas y marcar  esta como solución aprobada